# WildFly - WrappedResultSetJDK8 cannot be cast to OracleResultSet

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, wildfly

**org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedResultSetJDK8 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet**

I have been using WildFly13 in domain mode to deploy an application that connects to Oracle database, this one use a CLOB field and currently I'm having the error mentioned above.

Previously the same application was deployed over WebLogic12 and the same issue was solved with the property **Wrap Data Types**. For WildFly I have been testing different solutions but with not success, the problem keeps showing.
I tried the next:

- Adding as a global module to the profile, *org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters*
- Adding a *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* file as follows:

---

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
         <dependencies>
                <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" slot="main"/>
                <module name="com.oracle" slot="main"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

---

- Removing the *ojdbc6.jar* from the deployment

I would like to know if there is another option I could try to solve the issue

PS: I'm not able to modify the code

Thanks

Comment: this means you have two different libraries on your classpath. Check of ojdbc or any other Oracle driver jar under modules and in the war file.

Comment: @AtulK Currently I don't have the ojdbc library in the classpath, the application works in general until I use some options that works with CLOB fields in the database

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repo? I can try to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @AtulK I don't that repo, we could find a solution overwriting that class. What I could check was the line throwing the error: `oracle.sql.CLOB clob = ((oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet)result).getCLOB(0);` where result is the ResultSet